# Why do train departure boards use orange text on black background?

Tags: physical, text, color-scheme, readability

At train stations in the UK (and I also noticed in Italy) - the departure/arrival boards use orange text on a black background.

[image]

However, at airports there appear to be a much wider variety of colour and layout for the same use case.

Is there a reason or any research on why departure board are different for different modes of transport, and whether orange on black is significantly more readable than white on black?

Comment: In Germany it's different, they are using a blue background with white text. Any combination of colors that makes it readable is ok.

Comment: With many things like this I assume readability decisions were not the core driver. More likely - "we need some display boards, go and find the cheapest provider that looks ok".

Comment: It's an interesting convention that can also be seen in roadside [variable-message (matrix) signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-message_sign), which use the same or similar technology.

Comment: Notice how the lights are orange but the printed text is white.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Rail_corporate_liveries

The reason I'd guess is that black and yellow/orange are the train colours (intercity 225=the icon of the 80s), even in these days of multiple private operators it holds over. A quick search of network rail shows their trains in yellow and black too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply because orange LEDs used to be brighter and more reliable than white ones. The [Rail Vehicle Accessibilty Regulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_Vehicle_Accessibility_Regulations) require specific amounts of contrast in on board information screens and may cover on-station screens also.

[Infotec](http://www.infotec.co.uk/) is one of the more commonly seen manufacturers of these displays in the UK, and do now offer white-on-black screens which have been rolled out to some locations, as well as white-on-blue LCD screens similar to those seen in Germany.